# Django AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'iter'

Tags: python, django, django-admin

On Django admin when I tried to update the existing data I’m getting an error,

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '__iter__'
```

models.py

```
class SSPDrive(models.Model):

    drive_year = models.DateField(verbose_name='Drive year', null=True, blank=True, help_text="Enter drive year.")

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "SSP Drive"
        verbose_name_plural = "SSP Drives"

    def __str__(self):
        return str('SSP'+str(self.drive_year.year)[-2:]+'T'+str(self.drive_year.year+1)[-2:])

class SSPDriveAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    save_as = True

    class Meta:
        model = SSPDrive

admin.site.register(SSPDrive, SSPDriveAdmin)
```

Can someone help me out, why am I getting this error…

Comment: You should find out about [string formatting](https://pyformat.info/) in Python and code formatting here on SO.

Comment: It is small bug in django 1.10 so try with django 1.11 if you face this issue

Answer (score 0):

`ModelAdmin` Meta class no effect. The `ModelAdmin` does not use a `Meta` class. And you can specify model when registering it.

```
class SSPDriveAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass
admin.site.register(SSPDrive, SSPDriveAdmin)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is small bug in django 1.10 so try with django 1.11 if you face this issue